# Suck it up and be a man

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

I came across this expression today and found that the term means to endure the hardship phase a man is going through without whining which is what is stereo typically expected from a guy. I went through the wiki page (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suck_it_up) but did not find why the word 'suck'was used in this phrase. I suppose there's a reference behind it in analogy to drinking something unpleasant and then dealing with the irritation it might create in the body. Otherwise, one could use other verbs such as 'hear' or 'eat' and frankly I don't see anything wrong with them. I would like to know what was the inspiration behind using the word 'suck' and what was the origin of this phrase?

**EDIT**: The possible duplicate question([What does “suck it up and go” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32560/what-does-suck-it-up-and-go-mean)) tries to answer about origin which may or may not be true. There is no definite answer to it. Besides the question is mainly about the meaning and not the origin per se.

Comment: @Josh61 Thank you for the link. It is helpful but I still didn't find the answer to my question.

Comment: ***Suck It Up*** : http://www.slate.com/articles/life/the_good_word/2006/08/suck_it_up.html

Comment: 4 of the 6 answers to the original question *attempt* to address this issue, but the bottom line, as pointed out in my answer there, is that [the origin is "uncertain"](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/32569/2637). FWIW, the earliest two written instances I can find for *suck it up and [do whatever you have to do]* are [1974](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Suck+it+up+and+go+out+there+and+play%22) and [1979](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Suck+it+up+and+beardown%22), both in a ***football*** context.

Comment: ...and the 1974 link above specifically says it's ***a well-worn football adage*** - so although it might be interesting, the "pilot sucking up vomit in his mask" idea is incredibly unlikely. As I pointed out in my answer, it's a straightforward extension from ***suck/pull in/up your chest/stomach*** (i.e. - *stand tall, look confident*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers there is an earlier (December 1969)  semi-famous quote from football coach Darrell Royal "Every now and then you just have to suck it up and pick a number" https://www.newspapers.com/newspage/107070804/ and https://www.si.com/vault/1969/12/15/613039/texas-by-an-eyelash

Answer (score 0):

Suck it up and be a man is an expression. When it says suck it up it's referring to pain. Is pretty much like saying just ignore the pain and try to go on.