# A word for forcing oneself to do something one dislikes

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

What is word for forcing oneself to do something one dislikes or in general doing something one hates?

I can't use [self-] "discipline" because I'm thinking along negative connotations almost of puritanical self-punishment, doing something that one might find distasteful, unnatural, because it's somehow ennobling.

Comment: Why not *discipline* or *self-discipline*? Or *ascesis.* Those words would seem to express what you want better than anything else I can think of.

Comment: Oooh, @Cerberus, +1 for the *ascesis*. Can I add it as an alternative to *asceticism* in my answer?

Comment: Because I'm looking for a slightly religious, maybe puritanical and negative connotation. '(Self-)discipline' is generally positive, I think.

Comment: "Eat your vegetables", "screw up your courage", "choke it down"?

Comment: Related: [What does “suck it up and go” mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32560/) Personally, I always like to encourage people with [Learn thou of Faustus manly fortitude.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7X0YAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT247&lpg=PT247&dq=%22Learn+thou+of+Faustus+manly+fortitude%22&source=bl&ots=f2t_DYiRUR&sig=z0u0sbd6VteYjyqTtFe0JB9hr9c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5mMz-oKjNAhVLLsAKHS8JDgAQ6AEIOzAF#v=onepage&q=%22Learn%20thou%20of%20Faustus%20manly%20fortitude%22&f=false)

Comment: @DanBron: You can add anything you like! I hate copyright (although of course there is more to it).

Comment: @MattS.: Discipline can by all means be religious, and especially puritanical. It can be negative or positive.

Comment: The phrase "muster up the energy (or courage or resolve)" will work.

Comment: @Cerberus "Puritanical", that will work for me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Staying within your religious context, this practice is known as

> **Mortification of the flesh** is an act by which a individual or group seeks to mortify, or put to death, their sinful nature, as a part of the process of **sanctification**.
>   In Christianity, common forms of mortification that are practiced to this day include **fasting**, **abstinence**, as well as **pious kneeling**.
>   <sub>Wikipedia</sub>

Another example of *mortification of the flesh* is [self-flagellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-flagellation).

A related, and complementary, concept is ***asceticism***, which, as opposed to doing something one finds distasteful, is forgoing or abstaining from things one *would like* to do.

> **Asceticism** is a lifestyle characterized by **abstinence from worldly pleasures, often for the purpose of pursuing spiritual goals**.<sub>Wikipedia</sub>

An alternative to *asceticism*, [suggested by @Cerebus in the comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332570/a-word-for-forcing-oneself-to-do-something-one-dislikes/332571#comment758903_332570), is ***ascesis***, which I like better than *asceticism* because it seems more personal, more of a practice specific to that one individual.

Finally, [a common conversational rebuke](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332570/a-word-for-forcing-oneself-to-do-something-one-dislikes/332571#comment758901_332571) in these contexts is:

> *Oh, don't be such a martyr!*

Which [@Matt S cleverly reduced](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332570/a-word-for-forcing-oneself-to-do-something-one-dislikes/332571#comment758902_332571) to ***martyrdom***.

Comment: I'm using it figuratively, but the religious side is pretty much in evidence (though not explicit). 'Mortification' is good, 'self-flagellation' a bit too far. The other suggestions are almost noble, so don't quite fit. 'Expiatory'?

Comment: Aren't all these actions supposed to be noble? At least in the mind of the practitioner? In re: *expiatory*, (a) thanks for teaching me a new word and (b) are you intending to use the word in the context of atonement specifically? To make amends for some past sin? If so, there are a wealth of words available to you.

Comment: Welcome. No, for an activity that one undertakes not for pleasure or out of necessity, but for some arbitrary, possibly pious reason of "you can't always do what you want", and finding that noble.

Comment: Oh, like *don't be such a martyr* kind of thing?

Comment: Ha! I may just go with 'martyrdom'. Great!

Answer (score 1):

I am left thinking of "taking one's medicine."  If this isn't the context you're looking for can you provide an example or more specifics?

Comment: Dan's suggestions are very close to what I need. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about *forcing* someone to do something. The words *dictator* and *dictate* come to my mind.

But I am not sure if those imply putting your force on someone else *against his will*.

Comment: No, I wrote "forcing oneself to do something", not "forcing someone to do something", in which case your suggestions would be good. Thanks.

Comment: Ah ... Do what you want, not what you´d like to. How about inventing the word _self-dictate_? But maybe I´ll have an idea where to look for an existing word.

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer.